# Django - assign m2m relationship in admin

Tags: django, django-models, m2m

In the app I'm building some users have the role "Coder" and are assigned to "Assignments".
What I can't seem to get working is the process of an Admin assigning Coders to Assignments.

Here is the Model-Code I have so far (probably totally wrong):

```
class Coder(models.Model):
"""Every user can be a coder. Coders are assigned to Assignments"""
user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Admin:
    list_display = ('',)
    search_fields = ('',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"Coders"

class Assignment(models.Model):
"""(Assignment description)"""
title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
start_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
end_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
country = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
coders = models.ManyToManyField(Coder)

class Admin:
    list_display = ('',)
    search_fields = ('',)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"Assignment"
```

And this is the admin-code:

```
class AssignmentCoderInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Assignment.coders.through
can_delete = False
verbose_name_plural = 'coder'

class AssignmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fieldsets = [
    ('Assignment', {'fields': ['title', 'start_year', 'end_year']})
]
inlines = (AssignmentCoderInline,)

class CoderInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = Coder
can_delete = False
verbose_name_plural = 'coder'
```

Now, when i'm in the admin, I want to create an assignment and add coders to it.
Yet all I see when trying to do so is this:
[image: This is what I see in the admin]

How can I add one coder/user to an assignment, so I can later show him in a view all the assignments he has?
This is probably a really dumb question, but please answer anyways, I greatly appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it looks like you want to call a coder to a view, and then show all the assignments for an a user.

First, I might start by assigning a [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to the coder and assignment models relationships with each other, so you can easily reference them later.

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    coders = models.ManyToManyField(Coder, related_name='assignments')

class Coder(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="coder")
```

I'd then reference the user in a template as such using the [one to one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/):

```
    {% for assignment in user.coder.assignments.all %}
```

Also, looks like the problem is how you've got yout models setup. After reviewing the `django.db.models.base` for the "models.Model" class and "ModelBase" class, it looks like there is no "Admin" subclass. You'll probably want to remove those to start with.

Next, the `__unicode__` field shows the default visible value which represents the object on the screen. In this case, you've forced it to be "Coders". If you had 5 coders to an assignment, you'd see "Coders, Coders, Coders, Coders, Coders" instead of "admin, user1, bob22, harry8, stadm1in", etc. Let's override the **unicode** to show something more meaningful. Since the coders field only has the user field, let's reference that by `self.user.username`. We'll change `Assignment()`'s **unicode** to `self.title` as well.

ModelForm doesn't have an 'Admin' subclass either, so let's remove that.

```
MODELS:


class Coder(models.Model):
    """Every user can be a coder. Coders are assigned to Assignments"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='coder')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Assignment(models.Model):
    """(Assignment description)"""
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    start_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    coders = models.ManyToManyField(Coder, related_name='assignments')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


ADMIN:

class AssignmentCoderInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Assignment.coders.through
    can_delete = False
 #   verbose_name_plural = 'coder'

class AssignmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Assignment', {'fields': ['title', 'start_year', 'end_year']})
    ]
    inlines = (AssignmentCoderInline,)
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you!
On thing isn't answered for me though: How do I assign on or many users (=coders) to an assignment in the admin? That doesn't work and I would really like to know how I could make it work :)

Comment: Well, it looks like you've already got that setup. When you go to an assignment in the backend administrative panel, http://i.stack.imgur.com/Omhuu.png allows you to add more coders (multiple coders) to a single assignment. If I'm not mistaken that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, it could be the fact that you're returning __unicode__ as "coders". Mind if you share the whole admin.py and models.py in a pastebin.com snippet?

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I can't choose which coder to assign.  All I see is "Coders", but have no way of saying "John Smith should do this assignment".
How do I do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer with what should be the closest resolution to your question.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you!
One thing: If I reference [CoderInline,] instead of [AssignmentCoderInline,] I get "<class 'coding.models.Coder'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'coding.models.Assignment'>". With AssignmentCoderInline it works perfectly though, thanks :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28552/discussion-between-lukaskawerau-and-tim-selaty-jr)